# MySql : Order by and Group By combining not giving the latest record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using the following query I am looking for a solution to get the latest record that having some conditions.
But it gives me the first record, not the latest. I think its only considering the group by
Please advise me

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `id_receiver`=1  GROUP BY `id_thread` ORDER BY created DESC

id   id_sender   id_thread sender_email   id_receiver      created(datetime)
1    2             2         51             1                2012-03-24 13:44:48
2    4             4         1              5                 2012-04-26 13:46:05
3    2             2         51             1                2012-04-09 12:12:30
```

Required output

```
id   id_sender  id_thread sender_email   id_receiver      created(datetime)
3    2           2         51             1                2012-04-09 12:12:30
```

I had done a test just swap the order by and group by , giving me an erros.

Anybody can just look in to this?. Thanks.

**EDIT** Edited question, forget to write id_thread

Comment: Do you know you have to use aggregate functions for those columns if you use groupe by?

Comment: @duke  you cannot swap groupby with order by because group by cannot placed after order by . What data type you are using for cretaed

Comment: Your created output value doesn't exist in your sample data, should it be "2012-04-09 12:12:30"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you `GROUP BY id_thread` when there is no `id_thread` column in your table?

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE id_receiver = 1 
                                 --- GROUP BY id_thread
                                 --- removed 
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1                          --- only show one row
```

---

Based on your comments, what you want is the latest (ordered by `created`) row for every `id_thread`, which is a different and more complex query. There's even a tag for this kind of queries, named [`[greatest-n-per-group]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM contacts AS c
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id_thread, MAX(created) AS created 
      FROM contacts 
      WHERE id_receiver = 1  
      GROUP BY id_thread
    ) AS g 
    ON (g.id_thread, g.created) = (c.id_thread, c.created) 
WHERE c.id_receiver = 1
```

Comment: ,there is id_thread , somehow  Iforget to add that ,it's the most important though.

Comment: Yes, your solution not work for me because , I need the latest records for the all sort of id_thread

Comment: Your question does not indicate that. Your result set has 1 row returned.

Answer (score 0):

if records goes sequential than you might SORT by id too -- if and only if it's created in sequential order --